# Linux Cert Generate

Tags: linux, bash, ssl, sed

I'm trying to generate one cert.pem from a running server. I'm using the command:

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -showcerts -prexit -connect 127.0.0.1:4709 2>/dev/null | sed -n echo '/BEGIN\CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/p' | tac | sed -n -e '1,/BEGIN/!d;p' | tac > cert.pem
```

But I'm receiving:
sed: can't read /BEGIN\CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/p: No such file or directory

If I use only the command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -prexit -connect 127.0.0.1:4709 2>/dev/null
```

its returns information from the server with the key.

Anybody could help me why my command is not running ?

Thanks !

Comment: Remove the `echo` from this command as just `sed -n '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/p'` and put an add the whitespace you are trying to escape in `BEGIN CERTIFICATE`

Comment: Thanks !!!! After I changed the command now I'm not getting more error but my file is blank... Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you leave a space before `CERTIFICATE` to actually escape the space?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This command works for me (executed on openbsd):

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -showcerts -prexit -connect 127.0.0.1:4709 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/p' | tac | sed -n -e '1,/BEGIN/!d;p' | tac
```

You do not need to escape spaces if you have the sting in quotes.
And there is no need to have echo after first 'sed -n'

*If anyone tries this command and has no tac - instead use command:  `perl -pe 'print reverse <>'`
Also use correct hostname and port.
So new command (without `tac`) is:*

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -showcerts -prexit -connect 127.0.0.1:4709 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/p' | perl -pe 'print reverse <>' | sed -n -e '1,/BEGIN/!d;p' | perl -pe 'print reverse <>'
```